# Spring Boot Application test build fails on Travis CI

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, travis-ci

I am trying to use Travis CI for my spring boot api but I get the following error when I try to build.

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 35.335 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.bodify.bodify.BodifyApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'registrationImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userManagementImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDbFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@653a5967. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bodify-shard-00-00-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-02-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@653a5967. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bodify-shard-00-00-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-02-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userManagementImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDbFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@653a5967. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bodify-shard-00-00-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-02-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@653a5967. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bodify-shard-00-00-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-02-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDbFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@653a5967. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bodify-shard-00-00-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-02-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@653a5967. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bodify-shard-00-00-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-02-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDbFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@653a5967. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bodify-shard-00-00-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-02-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@653a5967. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bodify-shard-00-00-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-02-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@653a5967. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bodify-shard-00-00-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-02-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@653a5967. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bodify-shard-00-00-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-02-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@653a5967. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bodify-shard-00-00-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-02-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@653a5967. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bodify-shard-00-00-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-02-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@653a5967. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bodify-shard-00-00-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bodify-shard-00-02-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
```

I get no errors when I execute ./mvnw test -B locally.

I can post the full log file if necessary.

I'm very new to building Spring applications so forgive me if it's something obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that Spring cannot connect to the remote MongoDB instance available at the address: `bodify-shard-00-01-o8kg0.mongodb.net:27017` and timeouts after 30 seconds.

There is allowed at the MongoDB management system the connections to the IP address of your local computer for development, that's why the connection can be established.

However, Travis CI operates on a different IP address and server, therefore you have to explicitly allow its IP addresses based on the operational system in the MongoDB management system of your remote cluster (or instance).

Here is the relevant Travis CI documentation: [IP addresses](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ip-addresses/). There is also stated:

> Knowing the IP addresses of the build machines Travis CI uses can be helpful when you need them safelisted to access your internal resources. Since builds run in a variety of different infrastructures, the IP ranges to safelist depend on the infrastructure your builds are running on.

The way to whitelist the IP addresses for MongoDB, you need to follow the instructions of your provider.

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I needed, thank you very much